# Replace all rows in Dataframe R

Tags: r

I have a Dataframe like this:

| State | Posting_Day | Title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Perak | 2021-02-02 | HOTEL MANAGER |
| Selangor | 2021-03-01 | RESTAURANT MANAGER |
| Selangor | 2021-03-13 | RESTAURANT MANAGER (NON-HALAL) |

I want to replace all rows in the Title column with a new string

Expected output:

| State | Posting_Day | Title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Perak | 2021-02-02 | ACCOMMODATION MANAGER |
| Selangor | 2021-03-01 | ACCOMMODATION MANAGER |
| Selangor | 2021-03-13 | ACCOMMODATION MANAGER |

This Dataframe has 273 rows. All rows have a different title name.

Answer (score 1):

[assume your dataframe is called a.data.frame]

```
a.data.frame$Title <- 'ACCOMODATION MANAGER'
```

Answer (score 0):

Tidy approach:

```
a.data.frame <- a.data.frame %>%
   mutate(Title = "ACCOMODATION MANAGER")
```